# Return Multiple Results in Linq2Sql without a stored procedure?

Tags: linq-to-sql, multiple-records, multiple-results

i would like to return two record sets from a simple database table with one Linq2Sql query. I know how to do it if this was using Linq2Sql calling a stored procedure, but I don't want to use a stored procedure.

#### Is it possible to do it?

I've [found an article here](http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/linq-to-sql-batches-and-multiple-results-without-stored-procedures-by-tony-wright/) that has a suggested solution, but i hate the idea of having to write up a massive amount of code to partially extend the current context?! like... OUCH!!!

*Just doesn't seem... right ?*

Is the suggestion in the article the only way to do it? Are there other ways (without using stored procedures and still using Linq2Sql) ?

Wish [Matt Warren](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/) was here to answer this :)

#### EDIT

I'm not asking about how to lazy-load / eager load (and using DataLoadOptions). That's a different concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially you may do this with Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) which I found from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx).  It's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz.aspx) on the topic, but does not specifically relate to LINQ to SQL, however [this one does](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2008/09/16/MARS+Is+Casesensitive+For+LINQtoSQL.aspx) and probably the one you wanna check out.

Having said that, good luck because it looks like there's a [bug posted](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366444) to Microsoft regarding how it doesn't work, and the fix won't be here until .NET 4.0!

Lastly I understand you say you do not wish to use Stored Procedures, but if you do, I found a really simple guide [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx) and [here](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-to-return-Multiple-Results.aspx) to get going.

Comment: thanks for the post - i'll check it out, now. RE: stored procs. i use them in my linq2sql (and love that!) but i was just trying to test some other things out :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the only way I've heard of it being done without a stored procedure. And you're right it does seem a bit excessive for a seemingly simple concept.  If it was me I just get the records as separate result sets.

Comment: That's what i'm doing right now .. which kills me :( i hate seeing multiple hits to a DB when i feel that it could be batched up.